# What "totalling" is modifying?

Tags: participles

> Yesterday, Fang told the court that Zahid and his family took 23 insurance policies for 12 vehicles owned by them totalling $10k .

1. What "totalling" is modifying ?
2. Shouldn't there be a comma before "totalling" ?

Comment: It's describing the "23 insurance policies".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comma might help you understand this participle phrase.

The sense is that the 23 policies total (to) $10,000. This presumably means that if the vehicle were stolen or destroyed then Zahid would receive $10,000 from his insurance companies. The particle phrase describes the "23 policies",

It is unusual to have more than one insurance policy on a car, so this suggests that Zahid was engaging in some kind of insurance scam.